# X type jag slow pick up on start up

Tags: engine

Hi I have a x type jaguar 2. Diesel 
Starts first time on key but does not pick up or respond to the accelerator for about 10 seconds 
This only happens on start up rest of the time runs perfect 
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: 2.0 or 2.2 which one?

Comment: It’s a 2.0 Diesel on 2004 plate 93000 miles

Comment: There are some very good people who own Jag X-types on JaguarForum.com - they have solved just about every problem on x-types...